# AC amplification

Tags: amplifier, ac, opto-isolator

[image]

document link: https://www.zorgeffects.com/index.php/en/blog/33-tremoloo-ooo-ooo-ooo-ooo
How can I use this theory to amplify an AC signal? my project is run through a 5V supply hence the MCP601 rail to rail amplifiers

[image]

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. What are you trying to do?

Comment: U11 is configured as a comparator, not an amplifier.  Figure 4 in the document also is incorrect.

Comment: Please ask a specific question

Answer (score 2):

Your design is good in principle, but suffers from a few gotchas:

- The [MCP601 datasheet](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/21314g.pdf) tells us that with a 5V supply, the inputs must lie between 0V and +3.8V. This means that your lone potentiometer RV5 will over-drive the input.
- Even though the op-amp claims to have a rail-to-rail output, that is only when output current is very low. At 10mA output, maximum output voltage drops to +4.4V or so. See fig. 2-20 in the datasheet. While the datasheet doesn't explicitly state a maximum output current, 10mA seems a good estimate.
- The [NSL-32SR3 datasheet](https://eu.mouser.com/datasheet/2/1418/DS_NSL_32SR3-2935237.pdf) states a maximum forward LED voltage of 2.5V. This means that we are somewhat constrained with regard to the maximum permissible voltage across R2. That will be significantly less than \$+5V - V_{LED} = +2.5V\$

As a first recommendation, considering those constraints, I would suggest limiting the potentiometer output potential to +1.5V, which will ensure that there's enough headroom for LED voltage and reduced op-amp output voltage. Choose R2 to pass 10mA with the the maximum +1.5V across it:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZ1Vj9.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

A better approach, which will permit you to achieve the full 20mA through the LED, for a minimum LDR resistance of 60Ω, will employ a transistor to boost the output current:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fydDx5.png)</sup>

By deriving the +1.5V directly from the supply, you will inject any noise in the supply directly into the signal, which will be reproduced as LED noise current. This can be mitigated as follows:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flpYbl.png)</sup>

A simple capacitor could suffice (left), but the best solution will involve some kind of voltage regulation to obtain a stable potential in spite of supply noise. I use a zener diode (right) to achieve that, but a TL431 would be extremely effective in this role.

---

Concerning use of the LDR in an amplifier, to control gain, that LDR is an electrically isolated resistance, and can be used as the feedback or input resistance in a standard inverting or non-inverting amplifier employing an op-amp. Therefore, the circuit you showed us should work.

While placing the LDR at the amplifier input is certainly OK, bear in mind that this will produce an amplifier with variable input resistance, which may cause problems. Depending on the source being amplified, which will have its own resistance, it's probably better to keep amplifier input resistance constant. This means placing the LDR in the feedback path.

The NSL-32SR3 has a maximum (un-illuminated) resistance of 25MΩ, which will change very rapidly with even the smallest change in illuminance. It's probably a good idea, then, to place an upper bound on that resistance, using a parallel resistance. Optionally, you could also impose a lower bound with a series resistance:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fc8HMY.png)</sup>

The parallel pair of LDR and R3 can never have a combined resistance of more than 100kΩ. The series pair of LDR and R2 can never have a combined resistance under \$R_2+R_{LDR}\$. So the maximum and minimum combined feedback resistance \$R_F\$ is roughly:

$$
\begin{aligned}
R_{F(MAX)} \approx 100k\Omega + 1k\Omega \\ \\
R_{F(MIN)} \approx 60\Omega + 1k\Omega
\end{aligned}
$$

Gain \$A\$ will be:

$$ A = -\frac{R_F}{R_1} $$

That makes gain adjustable between:

$$
\begin{aligned}
A_{MAX} \approx -10 \\ \\
A_{MIN} \approx -0.1 \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: Thank you but how would I amplify my signal from this? btw the information you gave on the mcp601 and optocoupler is really useful and tells me the limitations I can improve in my circuit

Comment: @zug Since the LDR in the opto-coupler is completely isolated, you can use it exactly as you would use any normal resistor, as the feedback or input resistor in an inverting/non-inverting amplifier, for instance. That's exactly what you did in your design, and I see no problem with that.

Comment: @zug I'll add some more to my answer regarding this, when I have a moment.

Comment: OK thank you very much

Comment: Why is it that when I swap your amplifier circuit for a non inverting one my output still tops up at -5 like it would in an inverting op amp like in your example also maybe it's just simulation but the isolated LDR fluctuates its resistance alot especially at higher resistances

Comment: @zug Perhaps it's because the non-inverting one can't have a gain of less than one. \$1+\frac{R_F}{R_1}\$ cannot be less than one. This sounds like an amplifier issue, nothing to do with the LDR. If the LDR resistance is fluctuating, then the LED current is fluctuating. Fix one thing at a  time.

Comment: Like you put the 100k resistor in parallel with the feedback could I have more resistors in parallel for steps between 1k and 100k basically how would I get varying gain in between 10 and 0.1?

Comment: @zug The whole point of this circuit is that it's a voltage-controlled-gain amplifier. Why on Earth would you want to set gain by adjusting feedback resistance instead? You set gain to something between 0.1 and 10 by applying a potential between 0 and 1.5V to the non-inverting input of U9. So do that.

Comment: Hi Simon I now have a LM318 so I can output a larger waveform driven by +10 and -10 could I just replace the mcp601 in the circuit and it would work?

Comment: @zug Your supplies and input voltages can be greater, at ±10V, but the LM318 is a high bandwidth device, which seems to be internally under-compensated. It might require additional frequency compensation to stay stable across the entire range of gains you intend to obtain. You might have to raise another question about that. To make this easier, you should try sticking to "normal" op-amps, with bandwidths of 1 or 2MHz.

Comment: So if my frequency generate.goes from 1k to 1Mhz I would need an op amp that has a bandwidth closer to 1Mhz otherwise even if the signal amplifies, it would be less stable depending on how high the bandwidth of the op amp is?

Comment: Could I not just use a tl071 at this point

Comment: Also I can still use the lm318 no? It would just be unstable

Comment: @zug To have gain 10 for your DDS signal you'll definitely need the LM318, and it might need some careful frequency compensation. Any cheap op-amp will be fine on the LED side, like the LM324, LM358 or TL071/81. TL071/081 will require bipolar +10V and -10V supplies, LM358/LM324 will work OK with 0V and +10V. Get familiar with the datasheets!

Comment: So a tl071 before the led instead of the lm318 and the lm318 with the ldr as a feedback for gain control?

Comment: Also I'd change the 75ohm resistor since now I have 0 to 10V instead of 0 to 1.8V

Comment: I have the 100k in parallel with the ldr, 1k in series with that and a 10k coming from the signal all on the lm318 and it won't amplify the signal

Comment: What happens is it goes from 16mV to 600mV never above 600mV

Comment: @zug I have no idea what part of the circuit you are talking about. Since you've created a new question on the same topic, please focus on that. I'm letting this question go now.